# proving coerciviness of a function in variational approach

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying numerical analysis of differential equations and for proving the unicity of solution and applying Lax-Milgram theorem I am stuck bounding this function.

$a(u,v)=\int_{\omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} v -\int_{\omega} \nabla u \nabla v +\int_{\gamma_2} uv$

where u and v are two-dimensional functions. $\omega$ is the domain and $\gamma_2$ a part of its frontier.

In order to prove coerciveness I need to prove that

$$ a(u,u) \geq c \lVert u \rVert _{H^1}^2 $$
, with $c$ a positive constant.

I can do $ \|a(u,u)\| \leq \|\int_{\omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} u\| + \|\int_{\omega} \nabla u \nabla u\| +\|\int_{\gamma_2} uu\| $

$ =\|\int_{\omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} u \| + \lVert u \rVert _{H^1_0(\omega)}^2+\lVert u \rVert _{L^2(\gamma_2)}^2 $

Now using trace theorem and equivalence of norms

$ \leq \| \int_{\omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} u\|+c \lVert u \rVert _{H^1(\omega)}^2 +\bar{c}\lVert u \rVert _{H^1(\omega)}^2 $

$ =\| \int_{\omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} u \| +(c+\bar{c})\lVert u \rVert _{H^1(\omega)}^2 $

But I do not know what to do with the partial derivate to bound it.